# Replacing Nodes Error. The node to be replaced is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, html

I can't see what I am doing wrong. I am getting a bunch of select lists (drop downs) and want to replace them with a `<span>`, so here is my code:

```
var selectListElements = document.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');

//select elements
for (var i = 0; i < selectListElements.length; i++) {
    var currentSelectList = selectListElements[i];

    //alert(selectListElements[i].name);
    if (currentSelectList.dontReplace != 'true') {
        var newNode  = document.createElement('SPAN');
        var nodeText = currentSelectList.options[currentSelectList.selectedIndex].value;
        var parentNode = currentSelectList.parentNode;
        parentNode.replaceChild(currentSelectList, newNode);
        i--;

        newNode.innerText           = nodeText;
        newNode.className           = 'tableBody';
        newNode.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
    }
}
```

But this is giving me the error:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.

I can't see how that can be the case! I am grabbing the parent, so it must be a child!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In `replaceChild`, the new node is the first argument, not the second. You have them backwards.

`parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, currentSelectList);`

Also, why would you do `i--`? Isn't that creating an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks TwiStar. It is legacy code I am working on, not sure why `i--` was there, so thanks for that too :)

Comment: Thank you for this, you just saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 14):

## currentSelectList.replaceWith(newNode)

Use modern vanilla JS! Way better/cleaner than before. Generic form:

```
target.replaceWith(element);
```

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience) - 94% May 2020

Comment: Note that `replaceWith` function is not supported in IE. https://caniuse.com/#search=replacewith

Comment: There's a polyfill for IE10+ on the MDN link in @Gibolt's original answer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith#Polyfill